# How to recursively walk through directories and subdirectories and record top level directory information

Tags: python, pandas, collections, pathlib

I have the following directory structure, directory named `Python-Pathlib-Scan-Directory`

```
.
.
├── File_Extension_Review_20220704.ipynb
├── File_Extension_Review_SIMCARE_20220704.ipynb
├── Project1
│   ├── data_1.1.csv
│   ├── data_1.2.xlsx
│   ├── data_3.1.xlsx
│   └── info.txt
├── Project2
│   ├── data_2.1.csv
│   ├── data_2.2.xlsx
│   └── resources.docx
├── Project3
│   └── Info.txt
├── data_1.csv
├── data_2.csv
├── data_3.csv
├── output.csv
├── script_1.py
└── script_2.ipynb

3 directories, 16 files
```

I want to count the frequency of file types (extensions) within using Collections `Counter()` and return this as a Pandas df by passing in the results as a Dict.

I have the following code that does this

```
dir_to_scan = Path("/Python-Pathlib-Scan-Directory")


all_files = []
# iterate recursively using rglob()
for i in dir_to_scan.rglob('*.*'):
    if i.is_file():
        all_files.append(i.suffix)

# Count values and return key:value pair denoting ext. and count
data = collections.Counter(all_files)
data

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"Extension", 0:"Count"})
df

Output:

Extension   Count
.csv        6
.ipynb      3
.py         1
.txt        2
.xlsx       3
.docx       1
```

My issue is that this summarises at the directory level while I want it to summarise at each level (Root directory, Project1 subdirectory, Project2 subdirectory etc.) instead so I maybe concat results together in a df, have an extra column specifying directory and show counts so I may group by later even, use `path.parent` perhaps?

Any suggestions on the best way to approach this?

Also mindful that I could want to use something similar when just concatenating files in given directories and not just walking through all and concatenating all files together at once.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python standard libray [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module and a [recursive function](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/), here is one way to do it:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def scan(target, results=None):
    """Helper function that scans a directory
    and its sub-directories for file extensions.

    Args:
        target: target directory.
        results: dictionary to collect results. Defaults to None.

    Returns:
        dictionary which keys are the scanned directories
        and values are the collected extensions.

    """
    if not results:
        results = {}
    results[str(Path(target))] = []
    for item in Path(target).glob("*"):
        if not item.is_file():
            scan(item, results)
        else:
            suffix = item.suffix if item.suffix else "no_ext"
            results[str(Path(target))].append(suffix)
    return results
```

And so, given a fake directory which contains several sub-directories and files with and without extensions:

```py
from collections import Counter

import pandas as pd

results = scan(r"C:\fake_dir")

# Count values and instantiate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [dict(Counter(value)) for value in results.values()], index=results.keys()
).fillna(0)

# Sort columns ("no_ext" meaning "Files without extension" appears last)
df = df.reindex(columns=sorted(df.columns))
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
                                          .docx  .ini  .jpeg  .jpg  .pdf  \
C:\fake_dir                                 1.0   1.0    0.0   0.0   1.0   
C:\fake_dir\fake_data                       0.0   0.0    0.0   4.0   0.0   
C:\fake_dir\fake_data\empty_dir             0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0   
C:\fake_dir\fake_data\source_dir            0.0   0.0    1.0   2.0   0.0   
C:\fake_dir\fake_data\source_dir\sub_dir    0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0   

                                          .png  .raw  .tif  no_ext  
C:\fake_dir                                0.0   0.0   0.0     0.0  
C:\fake_dir\fake_data                      0.0   0.0   0.0     1.0  
C:\fake_dir\fake_data\empty_dir            0.0   0.0   0.0     0.0  
C:\fake_dir\fake_data\source_dir           1.0   0.0   2.0     0.0  
C:\fake_dir\fake_data\source_dir\sub_dir   0.0   1.0   0.0     1.0
```